NextAuth logging out when JWT expires
I have been trying to make this log out with no luck.
I have a mongodb adapter with JWT strategy. Max Age set to 20 seconds so I can have this expire fast and not waste time waiting.
My jwt and session callbacks are:
     async session({ session, user, token }) {
      console.log('session----------', session, user, token)
      if (token?.accessToken) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      }
      if (token?.sub) {
        session.user.id = token.sub
      }
      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, trigger }) {
      console.log('jwt------------', token, user, account, profile, trigger)
      if (trigger === "signUp") {
        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-user-id': user.id 
          } as HeadersInit
        })
        console.log('JWT - NEW USER!!')
      }
      return token
    }

Seems like even though my session should be expired, I keep getting in the dev tools that my __Secure-authjs.session-token expires in 1 month.
I want the session to expire in whatever value I set in
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 20,
  },

And also log out the user, so when I try to reach a protected URL (i.e. /secured/dashboard) I can redirect to a public route (i.e. /dashboard)
Using
"next": "latest",
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20"

